# Why this structure is diastereomers instead of enantiomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, molecular-structure, isomers, chirality

In this diagram optical isomers has divided in to 2 categories, one is diastereomers and enantiomers. Is the example for diastereomers correct? For me its looks like enantiomers
[image: isomers flowchart]

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Are the carbons bearing the Br the same?. What about the carbons bearing Cl?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you think they are enantiomers. They are actuallually diastereomers as stated:

[image: Stereoisomers]

As depicted, the compound to the left is $(2R,3S)$- while the compound to the right is $(2R,3R)$-. Thus, they are pair of diastereomers.

To be enantiomers, either the compound to the left should be $(2S,3S)$- or the compound to the right should be $(2S,3R)$-.